# pandas: use value_counts in an apply function

Tags: python, pandas, apply

Here is a toy example of my pandas dataframe:

```
    country_market  language_market
0   United States   English
1   United States   French
2   Not used    Not used
3   Canada OR United States English
4   Germany English
5   United Kingdom  French
6   United States   German
7   United Kingdom  English
8   United Kingdom  English
9   Not used    Not used
10  United States   French
11  United States   English
12  United Kingdom  English
13  United States   French
14  Not used    English
15  Not used    English
16  United States   French
17  United States   Not used
18  Not used    English
19  United States   German
```

I want to add a column `top_country` that shows whether the value in `country_market` is one of the top two most commonly seen countries in the data. If it is, I want the new `top_country` column show the value in `country_market` and if not, then I want it to show "Other". I want to repeat this process for`language_market` (and a whole load of other market columns I don't show here).

This is how I'd like the data to look after processing:

```
    country_market  language_market top_country top_language
0   United States   English United States   English
1   United States   French  United States   French
2   Not used    Not used    Not used    Other
3   Canada OR United States English Other   English
4   Germany English Other   English
5   United Kingdom  French  Other   French
6   United States   German  United States   Other
7   United Kingdom  English Other   English
8   United Kingdom  English Other   English
9   Not used    Not used    Not used    Other
10  United States   French  United States   French
11  United States   English United States   English
12  United Kingdom  English Other   English
13  United States   French  United States   French
14  Not used    English Not used    English
15  Not used    English Not used    English
16  United States   French  United States   French
17  United States   Not used    United States   Other
18  Not used    English Not used    English
19  United States   German  United States   Other
```

I made a function `original_top_markets_function` to do this, but I couldn't figure how to pass the `value_counts` part of my function to pandas `apply`. I kept getting `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value_counts'`.

```
def original_top_markets_function(x):
top2 = x.value_counts().nlargest(2).index
for i in x:
    if i in top2: 
        return i
    else: 
        return 'Other'
```

I know this is because `apply` is looking at each element in my target column, but I also need the function to consider the whole column at once, so that I can use `value_counts`. I don't know how to do that.

So I have come up with this `top_markets` function as a solution, using a list, which does what I want, but isn't very efficient. I'll need to apply this function to lots of different market columns, so I'd like something more pythonic.

```
def top_markets(x):
top2 = x.value_counts().nlargest(2).index
results = []
for i in x:
    if i in top2: 
        results.append(i)
    else: 
        results.append('Other')         
return results
```

Here's a reproducible example. Please can somehow help me fix my `top_markets` function so I can use it with `apply`?

```
import pandas as pd

d = {0: {'country_market': 'United States', 'language_market': 'English'},
 1: {'country_market': 'United States', 'language_market': 'French'},
 2: {'country_market': 'Not used', 'language_market': 'Not used'},
 3: {'country_market': 'Canada OR United States',
  'language_market': 'English'},
 4: {'country_market': 'Germany', 'language_market': 'English'},
 5: {'country_market': 'United Kingdom', 'language_market': 'French'},
 6: {'country_market': 'United States', 'language_market': 'German'},
 7: {'country_market': 'United Kingdom', 'language_market': 'English'},
 8: {'country_market': 'United Kingdom', 'language_market': 'English'},
 9: {'country_market': 'Not used', 'language_market': 'Not used'},
 10: {'country_market': 'United States', 'language_market': 'French'},
 11: {'country_market': 'United States', 'language_market': 'English'},
 12: {'country_market': 'United Kingdom', 'language_market': 'English'},
 13: {'country_market': 'United States', 'language_market': 'French'},
 14: {'country_market': 'Not used', 'language_market': 'English'},
 15: {'country_market': 'Not used', 'language_market': 'English'},
 16: {'country_market': 'United States', 'language_market': 'French'},
 17: {'country_market': 'United States', 'language_market': 'Not used'},
 18: {'country_market': 'Not used', 'language_market': 'English'},
 19: {'country_market': 'United States', 'language_market': 'German'}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')

def top_markets(x):
    top2 = x.value_counts().nlargest(2).index
    results = []
    for i in x:
        if i in top2: 
            results.append(i)
        else: 
            results.append('Other')         
    return results

df['top_country'] = top_markets(df['country_market'])
df['top_language'] = top_markets(df['language_market'])

df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need working by multiple columns by [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) in some function, e.g. here `lambda function` use:

```
cols = ['language_market', 'country_market']

f = lambda x: np.where(x.isin(x.value_counts().nlargest(2).index), x, 'Other')
df = df.join(df[cols].apply(f).add_prefix('total_'))
```

Solution without lambda function:

```
def top_markets(x):
    return np.where(x.isin(x.value_counts().nlargest(2).index), x, 'Other')

df = df.join(df[cols].apply(top_markets).add_prefix('total_'))
```

Comment: Perfect, does what I need and I can use this easily for the 30 columns I need to transform in this way, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think u can just use:

```
df['top_country'] = np.where(df['country_market'].isin(df['country_market'].value_counts().nlargest(2).index), df['country_market'], 'Other')
df['top_language'] = np.where(df['language_market'].isin(df['language_market'].value_counts().nlargest(2).index), df['language_market'], 'Other')
```

If u wish to use your own function, you can use:

```
df['top_country'] = df[['country_market']].apply(top_markets)
df['top_language'] = df[['language_market']].apply(top_markets)

#OR
df[['top_country', 'top_language']] = df[['country_market', 'language_market']].apply(top_markets)
```

**Edit as per discussion in comments:**

```
def top_markets(x, top):
    if x in top:
        return x
    else:
        'Other'

top_country = df['country_market'].value_counts().nlargest(2).index
top_languages = df['language_market'].value_counts().nlargest(2).index

df['top_country'] = df['country_market'].apply(lambda x: top_markets(x, top_country))
df['top_language'] = df['language_market'].apply(lambda x: top_markets(x, top_languages))
```

Comment: Great, that does get me what I'm after! But, more generally, is there a way to use a function like `value_counts` as part of a function that I want to pass to `apply`?

Comment: I think that's more faster way of doing this than using custom function

Comment: Yep, I don't disagree about the speed of `np.where`, but for my own learning  I'd like to know how to use something like `value_counts` within a function that I pass to `apply`.

Comment: @meenaparam - check another answer.

Comment: Check the edited answer if you wish to use custom func

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadHassan, sorry, I've not been clear. I understand how to use apply with my existing `top_markets` function, which works because i use a list within in. What I'm looking to know is how should I change my `top_markets` function so I don't need to use a list to store results, I can just apply it row by row and return the result as I go. I'll edit my question to be clearer.

Comment: Check the edited answer

Comment: Thanks, yes, that's helpful, now I understand one way to do this. I've accepted the answer below because I need to apply this function to around 30 columns and I don't want to have to specify the value_counts as a separate line for each of those 30. Thanks for your help.